# A variation of an exercice from Chapter 16 (Counting and Choosing) of Liebeck's book

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, lotteries

The rules of a lottery are as follows: You select 10 numbers between 1 and 50. On lottery night, the celebrity mathematician Richard Thomas chooses at random 6 'correct' numbers. If your 10 numbers include all 6 correct ones, you win.
How many ways are there to win the lottery?

From my understanding, the requested number is given by
$$\binom{10}{6}\times \binom{44}{4}$$

Am I right? Thank you very much for you help.

For the sake of completeness, here is the original statement taken from the [book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uy_SCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=The%20rules%20of%20a%20lottery%20are%20as%20follows:%20You%20select%2010%20numbers%20between%201%20and%2050.%20On%20lottery%20night,%20celebrity%20mathematician%20Richard%20Thomas%20chooses%20at%20random%206%20%E2%80%9Ccorrect%E2%80%9D%20numbers.%20If%20your%2010%20numbers%20include%20all%206%20correct%20ones,%20you%20win.%20Work%20out%20your%20chance%20of%20winning%20the%20lottery.&source=bl&ots=SnrME7PvFV&sig=ACfU3U0jgqijsazjDKUHcO7HuYY-7F82cw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitj9r8qZSFAxWqTKQEHXwSCNsQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=The%20rules%20of%20a%20lottery%20are%20as%20follows%3A%20You%20select%2010%20numbers%20between%201%20and%2050.%20On%20lottery%20night%2C%20celebrity%20mathematician%20Richard%20Thomas%20chooses%20at%20random%206%20%E2%80%9Ccorrect%E2%80%9D%20numbers.%20If%20your%2010%20numbers%20include%20all%206%20correct%20ones%2C%20you%20win.%20Work%20out%20your%20chance%20of%20winning%20the%20lottery.&f=false):

The rules of a lottery are as follows: You select 10 numbers between 1 and 50. On lottery night, celebrity mathematician Richard Thomas chooses at random 6 “correct” numbers. If your 10 numbers include all 6 correct ones, you win. Work out your chance of winning the lottery.

Comment: The book statement you quote differs from your formulation of the problem in one important way.  "Work out your chance of winning the lottery" is less ambiguous than "How many ways are there to win the lottery?"  Think about how to count ways to win the lottery that gives a well-defined probability distribution.   Clearly your "requested number" is not itself a probability.

Answer (score 1):

I post here an answer based on the comments. Different interpretations lead to different results.

1. $\binom{6}{6} \times \binom{44}{4}$: (see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888153/a-variation-of-an-exercice-from-chapter-16-counting-and-choosing-of-liebecks/4888176#4888176))

   - In this interpretation, one first focus on selecting all 6 correct numbers out of the 6 numbers drawn by the mathematician.
   - Then, one needs to choose the remaining 4 numbers out of the 44 incorrect numbers not drawn by Richard.
   - By multiplying these two binomial coefficients together, one calculates all possible winning combinations where you've chosen all 6 correct numbers and 4 incorrect numbers out of the total pool of 50 numbers.
2. $\binom{50}{6}\binom{44}{4}=\binom{50}{10}\binom{10}{6}$: (thanks to users @Haris et @user469053)

   - Firstly, one select 6 numbers out of the 50 total numbers available.
   - Then, you're selecting the remaining 4 numbers out of the 44 numbers not chosen by Richard. This is represented by $\binom{44}{4}$.
   - Alternatively, one could first choose the 10 numbers out of the 50 total numbers, represented by $\binom{50}{10}$, and then Richard selects 6 numbers from your chosen 10, represented by $\binom{10}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of controversy has erupted over the meaning of the problem. To me, it seems that looking at the epithet **eminent**, the  mathematician has been entrusted the task of choosing $6$ numbers which are "correct" (ie winning numbers) instead of, say a computerised selection, and the question is how many ways "you" can win the lottery.

The numbers are divided into two: winning numbers $(6)$ and non-winning numbers $(44)$ You win only if you have drawn all $6$ winning numbers and $4$ non-winning numbers

Then # of ways of winning $=\binom66\times\binom{44}4$, and the upper binomial indices must add up to $50$, as I had commented.

And the probability of winning the prize would be $Pr = \dfrac{\binom66\binom{44}4}{\binom{50}6}$

Different interpretations will obviously give different answers !

Answer (score -1):

The number of ways Thomas can choose $6$ winning numbers = $^{50} C_6= w$.

The number of possible number combinations you can end up with $^{50} C_{10} = b$.

Of the $b$ possibilities, you must have bought the *one* $6$ numbers of which match Thomas' winning number set, there are $w$ possibilities for that.